# How to intercept and change data passing from DB to ListView?

Tags: android, database, listview, cursor, adapter

In my application I read data from database, put it into cursor and pass it to ListView using adapter. These data are numbers from 1 to 12, but I need them to be presented in the ListView as names of months. How and on which step of reading and displaying these data can I intercept them and change from numbers to text?

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder() or use a CursorWrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data, right before it the adapter sets the text to your `TextView`. It'll be done in adapter's `getView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
public String getMonth(int month) {
    return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may right a custom adapter for that!. If your data is cursor object you can write custom adapter class extending from "CursorAdapter". Other wise you can extend from "BaseAdapter".
call it by:

```
   ShowListCursorAdapter adapter = new ShowListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_list_detail, cursor,
      columns, views, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

In custom Adapter extends cursorAdapter:
Constructor:

```
 public ShowListCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor,  String[] columns, int[] views, int flag) {
      super(context,cursor,flag);
        mInflater =      (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 mCursor = cursor;
        mLayout = layout;
        mTo = views;
        mFrom = columns;
    }
```

Implement 2 methods in CursorAdapter.

```
  @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {//This will be called once
        mView = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {//This is called no.of row times
        for(int i = 0; i< mTo.length;i++) {//If you have single column no need of for loop
            TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(mTo[i]);
            content.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(mFrom[i])));////here you can convert number to month and display
        }
    }
```